# Using OpenCV with OpenGL

Tags: 14.04, opengl, opencv

I want to use OpenCV with OpenGL. It says the library has no GPU support because it was compiled without any. Is there an OpenCV library compiled with OpenGL somewhere in the repositories? Or do I have to compile it myself? Or is there some other way of using OpenCV that comes with Ubuntu with OpenGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK OpenCV in the Ubuntu repos are compiled without OpenGL support. When compiling from sources make use of the cmake flag

```
cmake -DWITH_OPENGL=ON ..
```